# Resolve email adress from x500 address in EWS

Tags: email, meteor, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS in meteor js app and I am using [lather](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lather) to compose the soap request.

I would like to get all meetings form Exchange, and I need meeting's organiser email address (SMTP), but it always retreive x500 addrress like:

```
/O=ABCD/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (ABCDEFGH)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=ABCD00000"
```

I have searched for a solution and found this:

```
NameResolutionCollection coll = service.ResolveName("/O=ABCD/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (ABCDEFGH)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=ABCD00000", ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly,true)
```

But I am not using C#, how can this be done in technology free fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ResolveName SOAP request should look something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563518(v=exchg.150).aspx eg

```html
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:ResolveNames ReturnFullContactData="true" SearchScope="ActiveDirectoryContacts">
        <m:UnresolvedEntry>test</m:UnresolvedEntry>
      </m:ResolveNames>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

So in Lather based on the other example on that page something like

```html
var lather = require('lather');
 
var resolveName = {
    'm:ResolveNames' : {
        attributes : [
          { ReturnFullContactData : 'true' },
          { SearchScope : 'ActiveDirectoryContacts' },
        ],
        'm:UnresolvedEntry' : '/O=ABCD/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (ABCDEFGH)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=ABCD00000',
       
    },
};
 
lather.up({
    body : resolveName,
    headers : {
        Authorization : lather.basicAuth(exchangeUserName, exchangePassword),
    },
    additionalNamespaces : [
      'xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"',
      'xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"',
    ],
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx',
}, function(error, res, body) {
    ...
});
```

Should work (but maybe some changes are required)

Cheers
Glen